Understanding taser circuit with MOSFET and push pull transformer

I'm trying to understand the circuit pictured. It's a circuit for a stun gun.
I understand the function of the first capacitor at the front, but I'm having difficulty understanding how the push pull transformer circuit is supposed to operate. The "order of operations"
I don't understand how the 2 caps, transistor and mosfet create the push pull effect. I suppose would be my confusion. The original source explains how to make it, but does little to explain it's functionality. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.
Source: https://www.homemade-circuits.com/diy-taser-gun-circuit/
*EDIT:
So this is how I'm understanding this.

Gate gets charge via R1

M1 turns on allowing current to flow allowing inductive voltage which also supports gate voltage increase (Back EMF?)

Once winding saturated, emf dissipates, which cause gate to close.

Necause of current decrease from M1 closing the winding changes polarity.

Because of polarity change, it helps support gate closing.

Once gate is closed, the cycle restarts Because now the winding can start induces voltage again.

The capacitor is there to "regulate" or set the frequency of the cycle.

The transistor is a way to force this quickly if the current sensing resistor triggers the BJT

The cap on top supports the discharge of the gate even if the BJT is off, or aids in turning it on when it starts to shut off.


I'm a bit confused on the oscillating part. Does the oscillation occur between the bottom cap and bottom winding?
The mosfet is there to trigger this oscillator?
Also, when the the current goes from the top winding to the cap, does this aid in turning on the gate?
I may be kverthinking this, but trying really hard to understand. I appreciate the patience.
If you have any material/websites I could visit to help understand this I'd love the input. RLC circuits in themselves are a bit new to me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why not use a circuit simulator?

I have not been able to find one that can completely imitate this one. Do you have any useful help? All I see is the mosfet always on, so there's no push pull for the transformer.

This is a self-oscillating circuit.
First ignore the NPN transistor.
When the input voltage Vin is greater than the Vth of the MOSFET, the dot side of the transformer (the lower one on the left side) is positive, having a inductive voltage noted as Vx. At this time, the gate voltage of the MOSFET is Vin+Vx, which means that this MOSFET is turned on much more, and the current gradually increases, which is a positive feedback. For the right side, at this time, due to the direction of the diode (dot end is also positive), it is cut off.
When the current reaches saturation, Vx disappears and the gate voltage of the MOSFET becomes Vin, meaning that the current starts to drop. Now the dot side voltage Vx of the transformer is negative, and the gate voltage of the MOSFET is Vin-Vx, which means that the MOSFET is turned off and the current gradually decreases. This is also a positive feedback loop. As for the right side, at this time, due to the direction of the diode (dot end is negative), it can conduct and transfer energy to the load.
The role of the NPN transistor is to accelerate this switching process and release the energy of the inductor.
You can check the Joule thief circuits, they have a similar principle.

Thank you. Both answers have put this entire circuit in a different perspective. I'm coming from the old school relay logic background so all actions happen a lot slower, and clearly that logic can't really be applied here. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

This is not a push pull voltage converter. The topology is called flyback.
The integrated simulator CircuitLab can at least show the operation of the first part of your schematic.

The MOSTFET gate will be charged via R2.
The current through M1, the lower half of the primary coil and R3 rises.
The voltage at the drain is falling, the feedback voltage V_FB at the upper half of the primary coil rises accordingly.
The rising V_FB strongly supports the gate voltage rise via the feedback path C2 and R1.
The voltage across the current sensing resistor R3 reaches a value, that enables a collector current in Q1.
The current through Q1 starts to discharge the MOSFET gate.
The FET and primary coil current is falling now.
The drain voltage is rising and V_FB is falling now.
The feedback path now supports the gate discharge current, even if Q1 is no longer conducting.
Quick turn off of the MOSFET and a fast rising of the drain voltage. This is the "fly back" moment in the process.
The transformer primary coil and C3 form a series resonant circuit. The drain voltage swings down again with this frequency.
The cycle restarts again.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The lower half of the primary winding carries all the current, the upper one just provides the gate charge/discharge current. So there is no need to implement the upper half with very low resistance.
The voltage swing at V_FB should be in the ballpark of +/- 10 V, so the turn ratio between the two primary coil sections is defined by the relation between supply voltage and gate drive voltage, here it is 1:1.
A typical transformer implementation is 1:10, which creates secondary peak voltages between 100 and 500 V.
Run the integrated time domain simulation to watch the circuit.

Thank you. I was looking at this all wrong in the concept of how the caps charge. Also viewing the transformer as a push pull threw me off tremendously. 90% of this now makes sense. I really appreciate your time.

Can you help me understand the series resonate circuit portion of this? I've tried many youtube videos but unable to understand the concept. Is the purpose to amplify the voltage across the inductor? Also, I'm assuming the inductor doesn't see an AC type of current, more like a pulse DC current. Is that correct?

Or is the frequency of the series LC circuit dictate how fast the entire circuit oscillates?
